# Reverse (or bruteforce) the FNV1-64 algorithm by knowing some infos about encoded string

Tags: python, hash, fnv

I have the FNV1-64 algorithm as a python function

```py
def fnv1_64(data:bytes) -> hex:
    hval_init = 0xcbf29ce484222325
    fnv_prime = 0x100000001b3
    fnv_size = 2**64

    assert isinstance(data, bytes)

    hval = hval_init
    for byte in data:
        hval = (hval * fnv_prime) % fnv_size
        hval = hval ^ byte

    return hex(hval)[2:]
```

And I'm wondering if it's possible to reverse or more specifically brute force it. I have a list of hashes and I know the 12 first characters of the input string that was encoded, and the 4 last, I aslo know the string is only composed of lowercase letters, numbers, and "-" and "_" (39 possible characters in total) and the average length excluding the beginning and ending is 42. Is there a way to reverse it or it's just too many possibilities?

Comment: Can it be reversed? No, it's one way only. Can you bruteforce it? Yes, you just have to try (39^12) * (39^42) * (39^4) possibilities (1.913142e+92). It might take a while but you could be lucky and find it sooner. PS: There's an estimated 1e+80 atoms in the universe.

Comment: 39^42 is roughly 2^222, but the output of the hash is reduced to only 2^64 possibilities.  So the expectation is that there are about 2^158 possible input strings that would produce any given hash value.  Even if you could find a string with the right hash (via brute force, or any other method), the chances are effectively zero that it's the *right* string.

Comment: This is what it seemed to be, I’m assuming there’s no way to make a program fast enough to compute this stuff.